# Spark Streaming - Kinesis - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, lazy-loading, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Is it possible to process or trigger a method/action only once per batch of records in Spark Streaming?

My usecase is to call loadConfigurations() once per DStream batch even if there are 1 to n records. Loaded config should be availabe at driver for further processing.

Ex:

> batch-1: 0 records in kinesis stream - no trigger of
> loadConfiguration()
>
> batch-2: 1 record in kinesis stream - loadConfiguration() called once
> and variables updated at driver level
>
> batch-3: 100 records in kinesis stream - loadConfiguration() called
> once and variables updated at driver level

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any specific reason for not using structured streaming? Also why not to load the config before hand at driver and then broadcast using broadcast variable? does the configuration keeps changing for each batch?

Comment: use case has complex computation rather than regular ETL. Currently config is loading at driver level and broadcasting for onetiime. But need to change it dynamically when ever new configuration update. 
Note: Processing records is of different stream input and Configuration trigger event will be listened to different stream.
so, for configurasion input stream, even if there are 100events in a given batch, i want to update config only once. (hope reason for this updation once per batch is understandable).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure whether I have understood the exact requirement. However, based on the question description and your explanation in comments, this is something which might work:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val config = loadConfiguration() //  executed at the driver
  rdd.foreach { record =>
   // do stuff here. e.g. config.get(). This code is executed at the worker.
  }
}
```

An important thing to note here is that the `Config` class has to be serializable as it will be sent to workers from the driver.

Also, note that this could be an anti-pattern depending on your use-case. e.g. for each batch, the config object will be serialized and sent to the workers which will add network overhead depending upon the size of the config object.

I would strongly recommend to check the recommended design patterns for `forEachRDD` construct and chose your approach wisely. Here is the link to same: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

Comment: I dont need loadConfiguration() to happen for every time processing a dstream. this should happen on demand while listening events from other stream.
Requirement: `input stream => process records` ;&; `config stream => load configuration once per batch if any records (events come to this stream represents a configurations refresh needed).` However if per batch morethan 1 records came to this config stream doing dstream.foreachRDD or foreach records makes config reload multiple times which doesnt need. So I need to update config only once per batch of config stream records.